# how to use date variable and date_add() in php?

Tags: php, date

I have a `$date` variable  and I like to copy his value in `$date1`.
The problem is when I modify $date1 value with `date_add()` the value of $date is modified too.

How to modify only `$date1` value?

```
<?php
$date=date_create("2013-03-15");

echo "date =>" . date_format($date,"Y-m-d");
  echo " ******** ";
$date1=$date;
date_add($date1,date_interval_create_from_date_string("40 days"));

echo "date after modify date1 =>" . date_format($date,"Y-m-d");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP objects are [passed by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php). So when you assign an object to a new variable *both* variables refer to the *same* object. To avoid this, you want to [`clone`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) the first object:

```
$date1 = clone $date;
```

Your code:

```
$date=date_create("2013-03-15");
echo "date =>" . date_format($date,"Y-m-d");
echo " ******** ";
$date1= clone $date;
date_add($date1,date_interval_create_from_date_string("40 days"));
echo "date after modify date1 =>" . date_format($date1,"Y-m-d");
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/6lU8j)

You can also avoid this by using [`DateTimeImmutable()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) which will return a new `DateTimeImmutable` object when modified so cloning isn't necessary:

```
$date = new DateTimeImmutable("2013-03-15");
echo "date =>" . $date->format("Y-m-d");
echo " ******** ";
$date1 = $date->add(date_interval_create_from_date_string("40 days"));
echo "date after modify date1 =>" . $date1->format("Y-m-d");
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/rSKrt)

Comment: Thank you very much Mr John, your answer is useful and solved the problem.